# How to condense verbose code for my simple card game?

Tags: python

The code works the way I want it to, but I feel that everything below `random.shuffle(deck)` is bad/verbose code. I am looking for any suggestions on how to reduce code and achieve the same output. For example, instead of writing out `Ace = 0`, `King = 0`, ..., `Two = 0` (the number of cards of that type played at the start of the game), I'm looking for something like `Ace, King, ..., Two = 0` (i.e writing `= 0` once for all cards, instead of writing `= 0` thirteen times).

```
import random

cardfaces = []
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
royals = ["Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
deck = []

for i in range(2,11):
    cardfaces.append(str(i))

for j in range(4):
    cardfaces.append(royals[j])

for k in range(4):
    for l in range(13):
        card = (cardfaces[l] + " of " + suits[k])
        deck.append(card)

random.shuffle(deck)

total = 0

Ace = 0
King = 0
Queen = 0
Jack = 0
Ten = 0
Nine = 0
Eight = 0
Seven = 0
Six = 0
Five = 0
Four = 0
Three = 0
Two = 0

print("Welcome to Card Game")

while True:
    a = input("Continue? y/n:")
    if a == "y":
        total += 1
        if "Ace" in (deck[total]):
            Ace += 1
        elif "King" in (deck[total]):
            King += 1
        elif "Queen" in (deck[total]):
            Queen += 1
        elif "Jack" in (deck[total]):
            Jack += 1
        elif "10" in (deck[total]):
            Ten += 1
        elif "9" in (deck[total]):
            Nine += 1
        elif "8" in (deck[total]):
            Eight += 1
        elif "7" in (deck[total]):
            Seven += 1
        elif "6" in (deck[total]):
            Six += 1
        elif "5" in (deck[total]):
            Five += 1
        elif "4" in (deck[total]):
            Four += 1
        elif "3" in (deck[total]):
            Three += 1
        elif "2" in (deck[total]):
            Two += 1
        print(deck[total],  "   K(", King, ")""  Q(", Queen, ")" "  J(", Jack, ")"
            "  10(", Ten, ")" "  9(", Nine, ")""  8(", Eight, ")" "  7(", Seven, ")"  
            "  6(", Six, ")" "  5(", Five, ")""  4(", Four, ")" "  3(", Three, ")" "  2(", Two, ")"
            "  A(", Ace, ")" "  [Cards left:", 52 - total, "]")
        continue
    elif a == "n":
        print("Game Over")
        break
    else:
        print("Enter either y or n")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `Ace = King = ... = 0`? But you'd be better IMO with a dictionary (or `defaultdict(int)`) tracking the cards than so many named variables.

Comment: @DeepSpace Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based. See also https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @Zeta Let's agree to disagree on this one

Comment: Just use a `dict` mapping card names to counts, then you get rid of your dozen variables, the `if/elif` cascade, and you can use a `join` with a generator expression for the `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Main one: every time you're seeing repetition of basic structure in your code, this is clear sign to consider using loop and datastructure that supports iteration.

   In your case, main issue is card faces — instead of using 13 variables to handle amounts you'd better keep everything in single dictionary — this will give you ability to work with it "programatically":

   ```
   hand = {
       'Ace': 0,
       'King': 0,
       'Queen': 0,
       'Jack': 0,
       'Ten': 0,
       'Nine': 0,
       'Eight': 0,
       'Seven': 0,
       'Six': 0,
       'Five': 0,
       'Four': 0,
       'Three': 0,
       'Two': 0
   }

   ...

   for face in hand:
       if face in deck[total]:
           hand[face] += 1
   ```

   If you want further optimization, you may use

   ```
   faces = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two']
   hand = dict.fromkeys(faces, 0)
   ```

   Main point here is to use same values to identify cards in both "hand" and "deck"
2. Once you have this, it will become clear that you don't really need `total` counter, because you can dynamically access all values in `hand` dict with `sum(hand.values())` (in reality, most probably you'd better remove cards from the deck when "drawing", and just use `len(deck)`)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? To my understanding, code doesn't increase values from pre-defined iterable, but defined by user input instead. How counter helps here?

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the code.

Comment: @Slam, `hand = dict.fromkeys(cardfaces, 0)` works fine as well, and with less code than your suggestion: `faces = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack', 'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two']
hand = dict.fromkeys(faces, 0)`